# Why are the macOS java application menu items disabled after a menu item's dialog exits?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I logged java bug 9052380 and Apple bug 36809266. I think it's a problem with modal dialogs and High Sierra. That's the killer because I want to use modal dialogs sometimes and it's unreasonbable to expect people *not* to use the latest OS.

I have no workaround yet, and I don't expect those communities to answer me quickly, so I was hoping someone here might be able to help me find a reasonable workaround. I have reproduced the bug in all versions of 1.8 and those that I can test in 1.7 (which starts with 1.7u4 on macOS). I have no interest in testing 1.9 because unlike jdk 8 installs, installing jdk 9 also replaces my java se 8 internet plugins with Java SE 9 and my other apps won't run. I cannot reproduce this behavior on Sierra but it consistently reproduces on High Sierra so the OS upgrade has likely broken some contract that exists between macOS and java. Furthermore, if I plug in my new external LG monitor on my 2017 MacBook Pro, I *cannot* reproduce the bug.

Insert video of uncontrollable mindless rocking in a chair here.

I have a macOS High Sierra (10.13.2) development environment currently running the Java SE Development Kit 1.8u161. The problem manifests neither on Linux nor on Windows.

DESCRIPTION AND REPRO

When I run the MCV example app and I click the app's Help->Item... then I see a modal dialog as expected. Then I close that modal dialog by clicking that window's close control. After that, the Help menu item should be enabled. But it is not. So far, the only reliable way I can get that menu item re-enabled is to either restart the app or click the Application menu's About menu item. Sometimes, I can move the cursor away from the Help menu and then when I click again, the menu item is enabled but that behavior is not reliable.

Here is how I compile and launch the app (you can see evidence of some of the different Java SE Development Kit versions I've tried:

```
JDK=1.7.0.jdk # this is u4, the earliest I ran on High Sierra
#JDK=jdk1.7.0_80.jdk # interesting jdk milestone release
#JDK=jdk1.8.0_161.jdk # currently the latest release
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/$JDK/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
javac -version
javac test3.java

java -version
# So far, using the apple screenmenubar is a requirement
java -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true test3
```

Here is the MCV example. You can see the use cases that I've defined that manifest the undesired behavior and the modal boolean clue that might be the only solution I have.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test3 {

  private static int usecase = 3;
  private static boolean usemodal = true;

  public test3 () {
    final JFrame me = new JFrame();
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu();
    JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem();

    helpMenu.setText("Help");

    mi.setText("Item...");

    mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (usecase) {
          case 1:
            System.out.println("usecase 1");
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(me, "a");
            break;
          case 2:
            System.out.println("usecase 2");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(me, "a");
              }
            });
            break;
          case 3: {
            System.out.println("usecase 3 usemodal is " + usemodal);
            JDialog d = new JDialog(me, usemodal);
            d.getContentPane().add(new JButton("irrelevant"));
            d.add(new JLabel("b"));
            d.setSize(70, 70);
            d.setTitle("b");
            d.setVisible(true);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    helpMenu.add(mi);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
    me.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    me.setTitle("a");
    me.add(new JLabel("a"));
    me.setSize(100, 100);
    me.setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new test3();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The earliest report we have of this issue is from August 2015, which suggests that it was happening as far back as Yosemite. I didn't have a good reproduction at the time or I would have filed it earlier. At this point it seems like High Sierra might have made it more reproducible somehow, which might give them some incentive to fix it.

Comment: Also even with this example, it isn't 100% reproducible. It's like if I keep executing the action forever, eventually it will happen, but the number of tries it takes to happen is variable.